# When connecting to the mysql database, an exception appears

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, connection, database-connection

can anyone help me, I am trying to connect mysql database, the server details are entered correctly, but when I call the open method, the program throws an exception.

[image]

I also used Server explorer, in this case the program sees the server, but I don't know how to use the database connected through Server explorer, that is, how to add it to the project itself.

[image]

Please tell me how to fix this error, or how to use the database through Server explorer.

This is how I connect to the database:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BDtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;user=root;database=clothing_shop;password=****;");
            sqlConnection.Open();
            string queri = "select world.countrylanguage.CountryCode from world.countrylanguage where CountryCode = 'ARM'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queri, sqlConnection);
            var value = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide actual code and more details. Where is the database running (localhost?).

Comment: I am learning how to connect a database, the database itself is not used anywhere, the database consists of three simple tables. In principle, I tried to connect other databases, but they have the same problem.

Comment: Edit your question and provide code. There is no way someone can help you if you don't provide code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you are using `System.Data.SqlClient` which is a  .NET Data Provider for SQL Server.

In your question you state that you try to connect to a mysql database. Use the appropriate nuget package for that

Answer (score 0):

You can’t connect using SqlConnection. you need to install MySqlConnection using nuget package. You can download from https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector and you can look how to use section from readme.

Comment: I used MySql.Data.MySqlClient and everything worked, but I also saw MySqlConnector. What is better to use?

Comment: Because, It is up to date and you check when did the package update? This is important.